# ¿Cómo mandar datos con System.out.print precedidos por una entrada con el Scanner en la misma línea?

Tags: java, poo

Después de haber emprendido mi aprendizaje de este lenguaje "Java" para iniciar mi trayectoria en ciencias computacionales, ha llegado el momento en el cual ya estuve listo para instruirme en programación orientada a objetos. Sin embargo, me estaba olvidando algo banal pero a la larga importante; y es, ¿Cómo después de haber enviado valores con Scanner, consecutivamente en la misma línea, imprimir otros datos?

```
class PersonaGetSet {

 private String nombre;        //Atributos de persona no inicializados
 private int edad;
 static int edadFutura;

  public void setAtributes (String nombre) {        //Sobrecarga de métodos

    this.nombre = nombre;                           //que asignaran valores
  }
                                                    //a los atributos.
  public String getAtributes () {

    return nombre;
  }

  public void setAtributes (int edad) {

    this.edad = edad;
  }

  public int getAtributes (int año) {        //En este método se fija

    if(año != 0){                            //mi edadFutura.
     edadFutura = edad+(año-2019);
    }
    return edad;
  }

  /*
    Mediante la sentencia System.out.print pretendo imprimir en la misma línea
    mi edad futura luego de haber ingresado una entrada por el Scanner
  */

  public void show () {

    System.out.print(" tendré " + edadFutura + " años.");
  }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

class Principal {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    PersonaGetSet access = new PersonaGetSet();  //Se crea una instancia de la otra clase

      access.setAtributes("Steven");        //Se inicializan las variables
      access.setAtributes(14);

    System.out.print("Mi nombre es " + access.getAtributes() + " y tengo " + access.getAtributes(0) + " años. En ");  //Se muestran los datos por consola
     int año = sc.nextInt();        //Se introduce un año posterior al actual
      access.getAtributes(año);
      access.show();              //Se muestra la edadFutura en tal año
  }
}
```

La cuestión es como imprimir la edadFutura después de haber introducido el año, de modo que todo quede en la misma línea. A pesar, de haber dado enter para enviar el valor de entrada.

Si hay otra manera en la que se pueda alcanzar el resultado esperado aunque sea modificando la estructura del código o en la que no use el Scanner, sino algo similar; ¡estaría genial!

Comment: ¿Y por qué no cambias el orden y pones el scanner primero pidiendo el año, y luego printeas todo el resultado? Si divides el mensaje final con un scanner de por medio te atienes a eso...

Comment: TIenes que hacer lo que te recomienda Corpex, al poner  `nextInt()` vas a crear un salto de linea si o si. PD: Por curiosidad ¿Por que en lugar de crear getters/setters en tu clase PersonaGetSet haces poliformismo ?

Comment: Re Corpex: Era para ver si alguien sabía si se podía hacerlo de esa manera.

Comment: Re Capt Teach: Porque estoy entrenando de esta manera y aun no he aprendido ese concepto.

Implícitamente lo digo al inicio de esta publicación: "ha llegado el momento en el cual ya estuve listo para instruirme en programación orientada a objetos".

Comment: Re Capt teach: ¿También sabes si hay alguna manera de hacerlo, aunque no sea con nextInt()? Agradecería mucho si sabes la respuesta :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desafortunadamente **no existe una manera para evitar el salto de linea con `nextInt()`** ... Quizás puedas encontrar una librería que te lo permita. Así mismo quizás sería buena idea (tal como dijo el compañero en los comentarios) que imprimieras por pantalla primero la petición al usuario del año que quieres que se calcule.

**Hay otra manera** que te puede dar una solución aunque no sea exactamente la que busques, y es que salte una pantalla de input para introducir el año y así conseguir que todo se imprima en la misma linea.
Usaremos la clase `JOptionPane` de la librería`javax.swing`

Solo tendríamos que modificar la clase Principal eliminando el `Scanner` sustituyendolo por `JOptionPane`

**Añadimos** la linea import:

> import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

Y **modificamos la clase Principal**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PersonaGetSet access = new PersonaGetSet(); // Se crea una instancia de la otra clase

    access.setAtributes("Steven"); // Se inicializan las variables
    access.setAtributes(14);

    System.out.print("Mi nombre es " + access.getAtributes() + " y tengo " + access.getAtributes(0) + " años. En "); // Se
                                                                                                                        // muestran
                                                                                                                        // los
                                                                                                                        // datos
                                                                                                                        // por
    String texto = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el año"); // consola
    int año = Integer.parseInt(texto);
    access.getAtributes(año);
    System.out.print(año);
    access.show(); // Se muestra la edadFutura en tal año
}
```

Introduciendo 2045 tendríamos esta salida:

> Mi nombre es Steven y tengo 14 años. En 2045 tendré 40 años.

Así también como consejo **te invitaría a editar el código de** **`getAtributes`** para impedir que la edad salga negativa, o en tal caso, que devolviese un mensaje de error tratando la excepción o que el resultado sea cero.

Un ejemplo podría ser el siguiente:

```
public int getAtributes(int año) {
    if (año >= LocalDate.now().getYear()) {
        edadFutura = edad + (año - LocalDate.now().getYear());
    }
    return edad;
}
```

¡Espero que te haya servido para resolver tu problema y que te ayude a seguir adelante con el proyecto!

Comment: Gracias :D me has ayudado mucho  Dale un voto positivo a mi pregunta, pls.